# Git: resolve wrong branch derivation

Tags: git

- I have a remote branch master, from which I derived a new branch issue-#4 to work on something.
- I did some modifications, I committed them, and I pushed them, but the work was not yet completed.
- Then, I found out a more important issue, so I derived a new branch issue-#7. I did a mistake: instead of checking out master first, I derived issue-#7 from issue-#4 instead of master.
- I did some other modifications, I committed them, and I pushed them
- Then before merging to master, I realized the mistake: issue-#7 contains the commits did on issue-#4.

How can I fix this mistake?

Current situation on origin:

master -> issue-#4 (Commit A) -> issue-#7 (Commit B)

So issue-#4 has Commit A, and issue-#7 has Commit A and B.

Correct situation to restore on origin:

master -> issue-#4 (Commit A)

master -> issue-#7 (Commit B)

So issue-#4 has Commit A, and issue-#7 has Commit B.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git rebase --onto master 'issue-#4' 'issue-#7'
```

will make `issue-#7` be derived from master. Then you can force-push `issue-#7` and also merge it to master without the commits from `issue-#4`. Be aware that this will alter published history, so if someone checked out `issue-#7` and based some branch on it, he will have to manually do a similar rebase than you did, but I guess in your situation this is unimportant.

Answer (score 0):

In branch `issue-#4`

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

It removes the last commit (Commit A) for issue-#4 branch. It must fix the mistake.

Comment: How would that help except of loosing the `issue-#4` commit. `issue-#7` is wrong and even there your command would not at all help to resolve the situation. ;-)